# Xcode code signing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I was trying to build and archive my app to submit it, when I realized that I had used xcode 6  beta to do that. So I closed it and opened xcode 5 and did all of this again. When the Xcode Organizer tries to validate the archive it gives me following error:

[image: Error]

What I have tried:

- Dis/Enabled iCloud function
- Regenerated provisioning profiles
- setup all profiles correctly in build phases
  [image]

Any idea how to fix this???

Comment: Have you check your bundle ID ? & What is the version of your XCode ?

Comment: I broke it with xcode 6 beta and now I use xcode 5.1.1. What should I check about the bundle ID?